# Where to check if an User is logged in in a Laravel Application?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, authentication, laravel-5.7

I've been using your advice and View::sharing all of my important data to all views. However, there is one issue I have encountered.

This code:

```
if(!Auth::guest()){
            $user=Auth::user()->id;
        }
        else $user=0;
        $temp=DB::select('query');


        View::share('cartnumber', count($temp));
        View::share('cartitems', $temp);
```

doesn't work when put in AppServiceProvider. Or better, it always sets $user=0, even if I am logged in. I thought it is because AppServiceProvider's boot function executes before the site checks if someone is logged in.

I then tried to use a BaseController with a construct function but that doesn't work either. The only solution that seems to work correctly is putting the code in every single Controller for every view! That actually works, which kind of confirms my theory.

But is there anywhere I can put this code without having to copy/paste it in every single Controller? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd put this in middleware.

Answer (score 5):

You'd likely want to put this code later in the request life cycle to guarantee an auth user because as others have mentioned middleware/session code has not occured during this part of the framework booting up. You could use a service class to call in all your controllers to avoid the copy pasting. Or If you'd like to achieve this using code in your service provider you could use a View Composer instead of a share this allows you to define a callback/or class that will be called right before the view is returned

```
view()->composer(['/uri-that-needs-data'], function ($view) {
     if (Auth::check()) {
         $cart = DB::query(...)->get();
         $view->with('cartitems', $cart);                
     }

 });
```

Check out https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#view-composers for more details.

Comment: Oh, I'd forgotten about View composers. Nice.

Answer (score 4):

`Auth::user()` will be empty until the session middleware has run.

The reason you can't access the user inside your service provider is because that code is run during the "bootstrapping" phase of the application lifecycle, when it's doing things like loading filesystem or cache drivers, long before the request is sent through response handlers (including middleware).

> Once the application has been bootstrapped and all service providers
> have been registered, the  Request will be handed off to the router
> for dispatching. The router will dispatch the request to a route or
> controller, as well as run any route specific middleware.
>
> Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/lifecycle

If you don't want to copy/paste that code everywhere, then one place to put it is in custom route middleware. You can list it after the `auth` middleware to guarantee a logged-in user.

---

Edit: View composers are another really good option, as suggested by @surgiie. The reason these can be set up inside a service provider (unlike your example) is because the view composer registers a callback, but doesn't execute it until a much later stage in the application lifecycle.

Comment: Actually it can run before the `auth` middleware, however it should run after the `StartSession` middleware for auth guards that rely on the session.

Comment: @apokryfos thanks, I'll see if I can clarify my answer